# Does a pagination mixin exist for ember.js yet?

Tags: ember.js

I've been writing my own pagination logic that would be similar to the Ember.SortableMixin but with support for paging. Does anything like this exist yet in the pre 1.0 build?

If this doesn't exist is a pull request welcome around this specific behavior? It's my guess that 90% of apps out there need simple pagination/sorting and having a mixin built in would cut out almost 60+ lines of code.

Thank you in advance

**Update**

I replied to another "ember/ pagination" question and my full blown (working example) can be found at the below

[Ember pagination full example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008838/ember-pagination-full-example/13033425#13033425)

Comment: I agree this would be widely useful. Proposals for additions to Ember core should happen as an issue created at http://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues

Comment: done - https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1386

Comment: For anyone who finds this, I did write my own pagination example https://github.com/toranb/ember-pagination-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple one that I've used: https://gist.github.com/1559628

It's by one of the top ember contributors.

Comment: any chance we could get this into the 1.0? looks like higher quality than what I was writing myself and it appears to be really well written/documented javascript

Answer (score 2):

i've just come across [emberjs-pageable](https://github.com/VisualGuruz/emberjs-pageable).
it looks quite nice at first glance, but i'm not sure if it's still maintained.

Comment: I actually wrote my own and it's maintained + test driven https://github.com/toranb/ember-pagination-example

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this one https://github.com/mathieul/page_wrapper

Tailored for use with Rails but could easily be adopted.

Really happy with it so far.

Comment: Which rails API qualities does it require?

Comment: the only part that looks like it might be a problem for me is the coffee implementation as I haven't yet incorporated coffee into my django asset pipeline