# Return count of total rows in ember data `find` or `findAll` request

Tags: json, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I need to know how many rows of a specific resource (App.User) exist in total.

I tried to return it in response, but Ember complains about not mapped properties and is expecting only array of records (`users: [ "john", "fred"]`). I do not want to make an additional query to the server.

Is there any clean way to achieve this with Ember?

Comment: +1, I was wondering about this in the context of [pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482977/does-a-pagination-mixin-exist-for-ember-js-yet)

Comment: Exactly! I need to know how many total records in result set is and use it for pagination...

Answer (score 4):

You need not make an additional query to the server.  Once you get the data in datastore from the server, it stays there unless some record is dirty and you run a `store.commit`

So, after you get your records by saying

```
users = App.User.find()
```

you can simply do `users.get('length')` and you will get the length.  When you do this, an additional query to the server is not generated.

Answer (score 4):

If you want this in a handlebars template, you can do `{{this.length}}`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by implementing `handleResponse` in my adapter and modifying the response in the way that Ember expects it.

Let's say I get a response from server similar to this:

```
{
  "count": 203,
  "users": {...} //user data conforming to model 
}
```

My `handleResponse` implementation looks like this:

```
handleResponse (status, headers, payload, requestData) {
  let parsedPayload = {
    users: payload.users,
    meta: {
      total: payload.count
    }
  };
  return this._super(status, headers, parsedPayload, requestData);
}
```

Then I can get the model metadata in a way [Ember documentation specifies it](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/models/handling-metadata/)